# Create mysql database and Import XML

Tags: mysql, xml

Hy
I am tryin to figure out a database structure after an XML file. I am relative to new to such complexity.

After I create the able I need to import it. The problem is that I think the xml it was made using joins. Can you give me some advice how to handle this problem. One row in my XML looks somethinh like this:

```
 <listing>
<id>GS0147</id>
<date_added>2014-10-9</date_added>
<property_type>residential</property_type>
<property_subtype>appartment</property_subtype>
<listing_type>rent</listing_type>
<geo_location>
<lat>00000</lat>
<lon>26.13860</lon>
</geo_location>
<address>
<county>Bucuresti Ilfov</county>
<city>Bucuresti</city>
<neighbourhood>Berceni</neighbourhood>
<street>Ion Iriceanu</street>
<street_number/>
</address>
<price>
<price>1100</price>
<currency>EUR</currency>
<price_type>full</price_type>
<price_eur>1100</price_eur>
<rent_period/>
</price>
<area>35</area>
<land_area/>
<title>
<![CDATA[ Inchiriere garsoniera Berceni,Oltenitei,Iriceanu ]]>
</title>
<description>
<![CDATA[
&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size: medium;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: Verdana;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&amp;nbsp;Va ofer spre inchiriere o garsoniera in zona&amp;nbsp;&lt;span style=&quot;line-height: 115%;&quot;&gt;BERCENI,&amp;nbsp; Oltenitei, vila, confort, contorizata total, aer conditionat, catv, LCD, receiver, internet, balcon, foisor curte, strada necirculata, parcare, termen lung.Investitia lunara este de 1100 ron.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
]]>
</description>
<images>
<image>
http://soft.echiparenet.ro/images/propertiessite/img_1240_15230.jpg
</image>
<image>
http://soft.echiparenet.ro/images/propertiessite/img_1240_15231.jpg
</image>
<image>
http://soft.echiparenet.ro/images/propertiessite/img_1240_15232.jpg
</image>
<image>
http://soft.echiparenet.ro/images/propertiessite/img_1240_15233.jpg
</image>
<image>
http://soft.echiparenet.ro/images/propertiessite/img_1240_15234.jpg
</image>
<image>
http://soft.echiparenet.ro/images/propertiessite/img_1240_15235.jpg
</image>
<image>
http://soft.echiparenet.ro/images/propertiessite/img_1240_15236.jpg
</image>
<image>
http://soft.echiparenet.ro/images/propertiessite/img_1240_15237.jpg
</image>
<image>
http://soft.echiparenet.ro/images/propertiessite/img_1240_15238.jpg
</image>
</images>
<url>
http://www.gabrielstefan.ro/garsoniera-de-inchiriat-berceni-bucuresti-1236.html
</url>
<rooms>1</rooms>
<bathrooms>1</bathrooms>
<kitchens>0</kitchens>
<balconies>0</balconies>
<appartment_type>3</appartment_type>
<floor>2</floor>
<building_floors>2</building_floors>
<air_conditionning>0</air_conditionning>
<internet>0</internet>
<television>0</television>
<security>0</security>
<phone>0</phone>
<heatting_system/>
<furnished/>
<wather>0</wather>
<gas>0</gas>
<electricity>0</electricity>
<street_front>0</street_front>
<termopan>0</termopan>
<wood_floors>0</wood_floors>
<parking/>
<garage/>
<paperwork/>
<build_year>2006</build_year>
<build_materials/>
</listing>
```

Comment: pull apart the xml. figure out which tags/children can be repeated - those go into sub-tables. anything else can go into the main table.

Comment: I did that. I creted the tables but do you know how to import the tables at the same time. Is there a way to make a multiple import in my related tables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much data you have, but if it were me, I would try to get a count on the variations on each field.  That can help id what is common and what is more unique.  The higher the count the more it is in common.

You can make a first pass at it by importing all of it and getting a count on each field (assuming it isn't too large to handle).  If you don't need all the fields, you can just export the ones you need reducing the overall size of the data you need to work with.

Once you have a handle what you are dealing with, you can start to really design the schema.
Hope this helps.